# How should internationalised domain names (IDNA) be sent in the Location header on redirect?

Tags: http, redirect, idn

Websites that have internationalized domain names will often want to respond to HTTP requests with a redirect status code (3XX). When they do that they will want to put the redirection target in the `Location` header.

If the website wants to use an absolute URI in the `Location` header, how should they provide their domain name? Specifically, should it be IDNA-encoded, or not?

(I'm presuming that if it's not IDNA-encoded it should be encoded using RFC 2047, but if this is wrong please let me know.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be a valid HTTP URI (as per RFCs 3986 and 7230), thus non-ASCII characters in the host name will need to be IDNA-encoded. And no, RFC 2047 isn't applicable here.